# Did weakref.proxy became hashable in Python 3.9?

Tags: python, weak-references

The documentation of [weakref.proxy](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/weakref.html#weakref.proxy) (Python version 3.9.5) states the following:

> Return a proxy to object which uses a weak reference. This supports use of the proxy in most contexts instead of requiring the explicit dereferencing used with weak reference objects. The returned object will have a type of either ProxyType or CallableProxyType, depending on whether object is callable. **Proxy objects are not hashable regardless of the referent; this avoids a number of problems related to their fundamentally mutable nature, and prevent their use as dictionary keys**. callback is the same as the parameter of the same name to the ref() function.

If I understand this correctly, the following code should raise an error:

```py
import weakref


class Model:
    pass


m = Model()
proxy = weakref.proxy(m)
d = {proxy: 1}
assert d[proxy] == 1
```

And it does so with Python 3.8:

```
  File "...", line 11, in <module>
    d = {proxy: 1}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'weakproxy'
```

However, the code runs just fine with Python 3.9.5!

```
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 18 2021, 14:42:02) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import weakref
>>>
>>>
>>> class Model:
...     pass
...
>>>
>>> m = Model()
>>> proxy = weakref.proxy(m)
>>> print(type(proxy))
<class 'weakproxy'>
>>> d = {proxy: 1}
>>> assert d[proxy] == 1
>>> d
{<weakproxy at 0x000001E3DCF665E0 to Model at 0x000001E3DC9DA100>: 1}
```

The code could be shorter if `print(hash(proxy))` is used which--again--raises `TypeError` for Python 3.8 but not for Python 3.9:

```
import weakref

class Model:
    pass

m = Model()
proxy = weakref.proxy(m)
ref = weakref.ref(m)
print(hash(m))     # >>> 159803004579 (Python 3.8 + 3.9)
print(hash(ref))   # >>> 159803004579 (Python 3.8 + 3.9)
print(hash(proxy)) # >>> TypeError (Python 3.8) 159803004579 (Python 3.9)
```

Does this mean `weakref.proxy` is now hashable even though the documentation states otherwise or did I miss something fundamental somwehere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes there was a hash pass-through in `weakref.proxy` but the next releases (3.9.6 and 3.10.0) will have this removed and `weakref.proxy` will raise errors again when used for instance as a key in a dictionary.

Longer answer: As [Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68164777/1617563) mentioned in his answer, a hash pass-through was [committed](https://bugs.python.org/issue40523) in May 2020. I filed [an issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue44523) since the documentation seemed outdated. However, after some discussion it was decided to [revert](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/2df13e1211cf420bf6557df02e694bf1653a0ebe) to the old behavior and remove the pass-through for `weakref.proxy` from Python 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11. This means using `weakref.proxy` as a dictionary key will raise an error in future releases (again). The developers argued that this omission was most likely intentional and that keeping it that way will save some headaches for some users ([ref](https://bugs.python.org/issue44523#msg396662)).

Answer (score 3):

This answer now appears to be out-of-date. See [aleneum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68273386/3000206).

---

Yes, it appears to have changed. [This commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/96074de573f82fc66a2bd73c36905141a3f1d5c1) says:

> bpo-40523: Add pass-throughs for hash() and reversed() to weakref.proxy objects

And the [associated issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue40523).

It happened about a year ago.

Comment: awesome, thanks for digging this up. I guess I should file an issue to update the documentation then.

Comment: @aleneum Yes, that would be a good thing to do for the community if you have an opportunity.

Comment: I filed [an issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue44523) considering the documentation. I would have created a PR but I don't know whether the pass through still involves some caveats and the documentation had been kept intentionally the way it is right now.

Comment: For people coming here in the future, this feature appears to have been removed (but at writing this is still the highest voted answer). See accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68273386/8903959

Comment: @JustinFuruness Updated to redirect to their answer.